# When does a convex set have a unique outward normal direction?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $C$ be a closed, nonempty, and convex set (in a real Hilbert space $\mathcal{X}$), and let $c\in C$ be a point on its boundary. When will the normal cone $N_Cc$ have a unique (nonzero) direction? My definition of the normal cone at $c$ is $N_Cc=\{x\in\mathcal{X} | (\forall d\in C) \langle x|d-c\rangle\leq 0\}$. I already know this holds for many simple sets like balls and half-spaces, but I want a more general result.

This excerpt from Rockafellar/Wets describes precisely the notion I'm looking for:

> When $x$ is any point on a curved boundary of the set $C$, the [normal cone] reduces to a ray which corresponds to the outward normal direction indicated classically.

However, the book provides no definition of a "curved" boundary. I'm looking for a rigorous characterization of this class of set.
Further references for geometry/convex analysis are greatly appreciated!

Comment: In finite dimensions, one could characterize C having a "smooth boundary" by: there exists a smooth function $f$ such that the boundary is the zero set of $f$ and the gradient of $f$ is nonzero on the boundary. The gradient gives the normal direction. I'm not sure if any subtleties arise in infinite dimensions.

Comment: $C^1$ (as opposed to smooth) will do it.

Comment: Supporting hyperplane theorem

Comment: @Renard the supporting hyperplane is not necessarily unique.

Comment: @Zim It fails to be unique when the set has a ``kink''.  So if you define $C$ as the lower contour set of some functional $g: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g$ is not just, say, Lipschitz continuous, but also Frechet differentiable, so that the derivative exists and is unique.  For example, there are not "faces" of a simplex that intersect, creating a point where $g$ is better defined as a subgradient than a gradient. I haven't thought much about it, but I imagine that if $g$ were strictly convex, it's sufficient for the set to be $\{x \in \mathcal{X} : g(x) \le  m\}$, $m$ finite.

Comment: @Renard I'd be really interested in reviewing a reference for such a result! Do you know of one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reference that might help you. https://ximera.osu.edu/mklynn2/multivariable/content/03_14_gradient/gradient

The first Theorem in the section ''The gradient and level sets'' states:

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$, and suppose $f$ is of class $C^{1}$. For some constant $c$, consider the level set $S = \{x\ |\ f(x)=c\}$.
Then, for any point, $x\in S$, the gradient $\nabla f(x)$ is perpendicular to S.

If the function $f$ is a convex function then the set $K = \{ x\ |\ f(x)\leq c \}$ is a convex set and $S$ is the boundary of $K$, i.e., $S = \partial K$. The (unique) gradient $\nabla f(x)$ is the normal at the point $x\in S$.

Answer (score 1):

Ler $p\in \partial C$. By the Hahn Banach Theorem, there exists a hyperplane $H$ meeting $C$ exactly at $p$. Locally around $p$, $\partial C$ is the graph of a function  $\varphi $ from $H$ to the line $H^{\perp}$. The function $\varphi $ is convex, and its local behavior control the geometry of $C$ near $p$. For instance if it is derivable at $p$, then the normal cone is the line $H^{\perp}$.

Comment: Unfortunately the hyperplane supporting $C$ at $p$ is not necessarily unique

Comment: Certainly, so what ?

Comment: I am searching for a condition which guarantees uniqueness of the outward normal direction.